# AJAX jQuery request return 201 OK but error event is fired instead of success

Tags: jquery, ajax, jersey-2.0

I am implementing Jersy service in the server side that returning 201 on POST method. But in the jQuery of the response, error function always called.

I am checking the application on localhost and launching the page from Windows IIS.

Everything I do, does not seem to help.

Jersy Java code :

```
@POST
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response createUser(InputStream is) throws APIException , Exception
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    UserDTO userDTO =  mapper.readValue(is,  UserDTO.class);
    UserDTO createUser = userFacade.createUser(userDTO);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(userDTO).build();
}
```

Jquery Code :

```
function createUser () {
        var data = formToJSON();
        debugger;

         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'http://localhost:8082/wfm/api/rest/users',
             data: formToJSON(),
             contentType: 'application/json',
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(){
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('error' + message);
            }
        });

    }

function formToJSON() {
        return JSON.stringify({
            "id": "",
            "firstName": $('#signUp_firstName').val(),
            "lastName": $('#signUp_lastName').val(),
            "email": $('#signUp_email').val(),
            "password": $('#signUp_password').val()
            });

    }
```

Returned Json :

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "firstName": "Avi",
    "lastName": "lastname",
    "email": "user@gmail.com",
    "password": "4321rewq"
}
```

Returned Headers :

```
 Content-Length → 102
 Content-Type → application/json; charset=UTF-8
 Date → Tue, 29 Dec 2015 20:04:38 GMT
 Server → Jetty(9.2.6.v20141205)
 X-Application-Context → application:8082
```

Comment: So what is the error message in the ajax call. Jquery tells you what the issue is when you display the arguments. `console.log(arguments);` My guess is you are not returning valid json.

Comment: empty error string , no details

Comment: check in the "nextwork" panel of your browser, if you get the response (returned json). This error may occur when you don't send any content.

Comment: Yes you are right , I do not see any Json response , Although when I am running the request with ' Postman' I do get the response I have attached above. Any Idea why I do not see the response on the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.

I had error in the jquery code :

```
 function createUser () {
      var data = formToJSON();
      debugger;

     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'http://localhost:8082/wfm/api/rest/users',
         data: formToJSON(),
         contentType: 'application/json',
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(){
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error' + message);
        }
    });

}
```

In the error function on the alert , I am using undefined parameter , 'message' . When I have removed the 'message' parameter.

**Also Running the page on Internate Explorer instead of Chrome**
The problem was solved .

Comment: You shouldn't have to remove `message`, just pass it in your `error()` function: `error: function(message){ alert('error' + message); }`. Your `success()` function should also pass an object (usually `data`) that you can access inside that function: `success: function(data){ alert('success'); }`